# Use IN to compare Array of Values against a table of data

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

I want to compare an array of values against the the rows of a table and return only the rows in which the data are different.

Suppose I have myTable:

```
| ItemCode | ItemName | FrgnName |
|----------|----------|----------|
| CD1      | Apple    | Mela     |
| CD2      | Mirror   | Specchio |
| CD3      | Bag      | Borsa    |
```

Now using the SQL instruction `IN` I would like to compare the rows above against an array of values pasted from an excel file and so in theory I would have to write something like:

```
WHERE NOT IN (
    ARRAY[CD1, Apple, Mella],
    ARRAY[CD2, Miror, Specchio],
    ARRAY[CD3, Bag, Borsa]
)
```

The QUERY should return rows 1 and 2 "MELLA" and "MIROR" are in fact typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a VALUES expression to emulate a table of those arrays, like so:

```
... myTable AS t
LEFT JOIN (
   VALUES (1, 'CD1','Apple','Mella')
        , (1, 'CD2', 'Miror', 'Specchio')
        , (1, 'CD3', 'Bag', 'Borsa')
) AS v(rowPresence, a, b, c)
ON t.ItemCode = v.a AND t.ItemName = v.b AND t.FrgnName = v.c
WHERE v.rowPresence IS NULL
```

Technically, in your scenario, you can do without the "rowPresence" field I added, since none of the values in your arrays are NULL any would do; I basically added it to point to a more general case.

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo. Your solution should work fine. I tested it and I get
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'. (Line 2)" . This is how I wrote my sql: ---
SELECT ItemCode,ItemName, FrgnName AS t
LEFT JOIN (
     VALUES (1,'00.LAM.01','LAMINA OTTONE SCHEDA 02.S00.01','FLASHER 2P 12V')
          ) AS v (rowPresence, a, b, c)
            ON t.ItemCode = v.a AND t.ItemName = v.b AND t.FrgnName = v.c
            WHERE v.rowPresence IS NULL

Comment: @MirkoNardi where is the `FROM myTable`?

Comment: thanks for your help! This is how i rewrote the code for my purpose: SELECT ItemCode,ItemName, FrgnName FROM dbo.OITM AS t  
      INNER JOIN ( VALUES 
                     ('00.LAM.01','LAMIN OTTONE SCHEDA 02.S00.01S','FLASHER 2P 12V'),
                     ('00.C00.600','SCATOLONE INDUSTRIALE 600X400X500 H','TFFFT 22222 BC - BANCALE 70X40')
      ) AS v
        (a, b, c) ON t.ItemName = v.b OR t.FrgnName = v.c 
       WHERE v.b <> t.ItemName OR v.c <> t.FrgnName

Comment: @MirkoNardi That seems like is for a slightly different problem (but I am assuming what you posted was more of a representative case). One thing I notice with it though is that you should be able to do without the `WHERE` conditions if you change the `ON` to use a `XOR` rather than `OR`.

Comment: based on your experice would it be possible to convert this script to mysql? According to this its' not https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-08/whats-new-in-mariadb-10.3

Comment: In newer versions, you could use a *CTE* composed of simple SELECTs UNIONed to create the `v(rowPresence, a, b, c)`. I think MySQL also has a similar VALUES usage now as well, but you cannot choose the field names used.